# How to align div into the bottow on another div

Tags: html, css

I want to make align the 3 child div into the bottom in his parent, i have tried with margin-top but it moves the hole thing.

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;width:200px;height:100px;">


<div style="height:72px;width:96px;margin:9px;">

<div style="background-color:red;height:47px;text-align:center;">This div</div>

</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the third div into the #child div.

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">
      content
   </div>
</div>

#parent {
   position: relative;
   width: 200px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   height: 100px;
 }
#child {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Style the **parent div** as `position: relative;` and use `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` for *child div*.